# Rhino JavaScript interpreter on Android Java gives only one output

Tags: javascript, java, android, interpreter, rhino

I'm using Rhino on Android.

My JavaScript code is -

```
  String JS = "

    if(2==2){ Print("true"); }

    if(3==3){ Print("true"); }

  ";
```

And the Android code for Rhino -

```
rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
rhino.setInstructionObserverThreshold(1000);
rhino.setLanguageVersion(org.mozilla.javascript.Context.VERSION_ES6);
rhino.setMaximumInterpreterStackDepth(100);
Scriptable scope = rhino.initStandardObjects();
Object result = rhino.evaluateString(scope, JS, "MySource", 1, null);
```

The output should be **true** 2 times. But I'm getting it only one time.

Do I need to set something else in rhino code in Java ?

Comment: Is Rhino a dialect of JS or something? This doesn't appear to be valid JS.

Comment: rhino is a Javascript Interpreter written in pure Java by Mozilla. You can run Javascript snippet inside Java.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino